# Python - Should I use read-only @property without init or setter?

Tags: python, class, properties

Trying to get my head around property decorators. I found a solution posted for setting read-only attributes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640700/alternative-to-passing-global-variables-around-to-classes-and-functions). Setting a private attribute and then providing a @property getter method makes sense if you can specify the attribute in **init**. But what about the case where you want to use a function to calculate a read-only attribute? Let's say you have a class that calls an attribute (e.g. state) from another class and then calculates a new value that will be made available as an attribute:

```
class MyState(object):
    def __init__(self, starting_value):
        self._foo = starting_value

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        self._foo = value


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def bar(self):
        state = MyState.foo
        return id(state)

>mystate = MyState('chuff')
>myclass = MyClass()
>myclass.bar = 183097448L
```

In everything I have seen about property decorators, I have only see display methods reflected in the @property getter function, never functions that set the value of the variable. However, from reading the docs my understanding is that @setter requires an argument, which I don't have in this case. Is there any problem with calculating the read-only value of a class attribute in the @property getter method as opposed to simply passing an attribute that already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem.  `@property` is just doing less than you think.  All it is is a bit of syntactic sugar to replace: `a = foo.x` with `a = foo.x.getter()`, and `foo.x = bar` with `foo.x.setter(bar)`.  That is, it allows you to replace attribute access with method calls.  Those methods are allowed to do anything they like, which is the purpose of the property.   I think you were being led astray by your first example where the property just passes through to an underlying hidden variable to make a psuedo-read-only variable.  That is not really the standard use case.  A very common example might be:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
    @property
    def area(self):
        return self.w * self.h
```

Area is a property of a rectangle, but it is derived from the width and height, and setting it doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: Your description at the top is misleading and incorrect. The result of a function call is not assigned to the variable. Try returning `random.random()` in a property and see what happens.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but I don't think I said anything wrong.  Calling random() in a property does exactly what you think: every time you 'access' the property you get a new random number.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the example! It was a basic question, but I didn't want to start using properties and then have to go back and redo them all because I didn't understand what was happening under the hood (wouldn't be the first time).